# Why (on a specific server) would ADO,NET get a Time Out exception after db result is returned and the reader is being closed?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I have some strange behavior occurring in an ASP.NET application that I am trying to fix.

I am getting the following error from code:

*Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.*

I am familiar with this error and many of it's causes. All of my typical avenues of trouble shooting have failed.

Here are some of the dynamics:

The server was recently re-built. So it could be a server configuration issue.

This error only happens on a specific web server. When I run the application it locally, and from other servers it is fast. I cannot re-pro perf issues with the proc in MSSMS from my machine.

- This tells me that it is specific to this server.

When I run The same proc using the OSql command--line utility It works. Fast.

- This indicates that it is likely something .NET related, NOT db related

Prior to this code executing, I have executed other Stored procedures on this server, and on this same DB.

- This suggests the proc may be related , but is not a "server X cannot talk to server Y"

I have gotten confirmation From DB owners that the DB has received the command, executed (>1second )it and returned the data.

- By tracing the code, I see the results are returned and it is not until I try to close the  data reader that the error occurs.
- In fact I see it takes 36 milliseconds to execute the stored procedure and iterate through the result.

It looks like the call to DataReader.Close is what is taking time, and eventually timing out.

I have increased the max Pool from 31 to 100.

Here is a sample of what my code looks like, how it is structured. I have been hacking at it for trouble shooting: I have added the explict close to ensure I know where the error occurs. There may be syntax issues: I have  made it generic, and may have introduced bugs in doing so.

```
    public double  GetMyData()
    {
        double returnValue;
       // Used in logging to see if code was reached & how long it took.
      System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); 
            using (SqlConnection cn = Connections.GetSqlConnection())
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = getSQLCommmand("SomeProcName"))
            {

                Log.Log.WriteTrace(string.Format("Execute {0} ","SomeProcName"),0);
                s.Start();
                SqlDataReader dr= null;
                try
                {
                     dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                     s.Stop();
                     Log.Log.WriteTrace("Timer", "ExecuteReader done " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms ", 0);
                     s.Start();


                    if (dr != null)
                    {
                        if (dr.Read())
                        {
                            returnValue =
                                Conversion.DBNullToDouble(
                                    dr[0]);
                        }
                        s.Stop();
                        Log.Log.WriteTrace("Timer", "dr.read done  (result:" + returnValue + ")" + s.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms ", 0); // I get Here
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Log.PersistException(ex);
                }
                //}
                if(dr!=null && !dr.IsClosed)
                    dr.Close();// This times out
                if (cn != null && cn.State !=ConnectionState.Closed)
                        cn.Close();
                Log.Log.WriteTrace("DONE "),
                                 ;
            }
        }
            return (returnValue);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

`dr.Close();` takes 2 minutes to execute. Just on this server. Locally it takes less than a second.

**UPDATE**

Per the accepted answer's comments: I have a proc that has multiple records. I am taking the fist one. Calling cmd.Cancel() has not fixed, but has drastically reduced the time taken to close the data reader.  Exploring this should help me fix the problem. I do not know why this is only happening on this server, as the server is a dev server.

Comment: have you tried to use it as well in a using statement?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have, The original code relied on a Using statement to manage closing the reader and the connection. I changed it because the Error was occurring in the IL emitted by the compiler. The source code throwing the error was '}'. I converted this to explicit close  to make sure there was not an error being hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see few problems in your code.

1. Try to use the Reader in a using statement it closes and disposes when finishing it.
2. You are closing 2 times the connection (when using

   `if (cn != null && cn.State !=ConnectionState.Closed)
                               cn.Close();`
   and in the `using (SqlConnection cn = Connections.GetSqlConnection())` -- this one do it for you at the end of the statement
3. In your code you are not checking if the  [DataReader.HasRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx) So if your Sproc doesn't return a value it will throw an exception in the `if (dr.Read())` so that could be the reason that's why you are getting sometimes the time out exception
4. If you only want to retrieve the value of the first column of the first row you should take a look to [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Finally 
I would rewrite your code like this (using DataReader)

```
public double  GetMyData()
    {
        double returnValue;
       // Used in logging to see if code was reached & how long it took.
      System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); 
            using (SqlConnection cn = Connections.GetSqlConnection())
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = getSQLCommmand("SomeProcName"))
            {

                Log.Log.WriteTrace(string.Format("Execute {0} ","SomeProcName"),0);
                s.Start();
                using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {


                     s.Stop();
                     Log.Log.WriteTrace("Timer", "ExecuteReader done " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms ", 0);
                     s.Start();


                    if (dr != null)
                    {
                        if(dr.HasRows)
                        {
                           if (dr.Read())
                           {
                              returnValue =
                                Conversion.DBNullToDouble(
                                    dr[0]);
                           }
                        }
                        s.Stop();
                        Log.Log.WriteTrace("Timer", "dr.read done  (result:" + returnValue + ")" + s.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms ", 0); // I get Here
                    }
                }             
            }
        }
            return (returnValue);
    }
```

Or (with ExecuteScalar)

```
public double  GetMyData()
        {
            double returnValue;
           // Used in logging to see if code was reached & how long it took.
          System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); 
                using (SqlConnection cn = Connections.GetSqlConnection())
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = getSQLCommmand("SomeProcName"))
                {

                    Log.Log.WriteTrace(string.Format("Execute {0} ","SomeProcName"),0);
                    s.Start();
                    try
                    {
                         returnValue = Conversion.DBNullToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                         s.Stop();  
                    }   
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Log.PersistException(ex);
                    }

                }
            }
                return (returnValue);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. you bring up some good points. My problem here is that the code behave fine on my machine, and (i did not mention this before)  has been working in production for several years. 

What I fail to understand is why the exception would occur after I have my results, and only on one server.


RE: HasRows-  Reader.Read() will not throw an exception if there is no data. It returns false. HasRows is a way to determine if the reader "Has Rows" without actually reading the data. HasRows has no side affects.

Comment: No need to check hasrows before read. Read will return false if there are no rows

Comment: Mmm your proc is not returning more than 1 row? if it has been like that way for several years, i thinks there was a change in your sproc or something, or after you changed the production serverit started to fail?

Comment: Th proc returns several. we only care about the 1st row. [long story.:) ] Keep in mind it works 100% from other servers!

Comment: mm take a look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133374/net-sqldatareader-close-or-dispose-results-in-timeout-expired-exception  I cannot explain why it works on the others server, but as far I know you might not close a reader, if you have not completly iterated it, thats why i was asking you if the sprocs returns more than 1 row. I suppose that you dont want to change the code on every server just because one doesn't work. Do you have access to the DB to modify you sproc to just return that one row and see what happens? this way the reader will be completly iterated

Comment: Adding cmd.Cancel has affected the behavior. rather than 2 mins. It takes 30 seconds. I'll follow this avenue te improve/trouble shoot the issue. 

Thanks!!